# How to list the table based on week or month from range of dates?

Tags: mysql, date

I'm using MySQL. I have a table `attendance` which looks like[image: table attendance]
Now i'm trying to display the leaves w.r.t. manager id using the query

```
select att.mgr_assc_fk, att.id_emp_fk,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'PL' then 1 else 0 end) as Planned,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'UPL' then 1 else 0 end) as Unplanned,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'SL' then 1 else 0 end) as Sick,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'HDL' then 1 else 0 end) as Halfday,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'AL' then 1 else 0 end) as Annual,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'OL' then 1 else 0 end) as Optional,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'H' then 1 else 0 end) as Holiday 
from attendance as att
 where mgr_assc_fk='1' group by id_emp_fk
```

which gives me output as [image: output]

where `mgr_assc_fk` is the manager id and `id_emp_fk` is the employee id from two different tables respectively.
Now I want to display the table based on week using the table `attendance`. Say if i choose week 30 it should only give me week 30's data or as same in the case for month's data. How do i achieve it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730) to get the first and last date of the week to filter with.

Handling months is even easier than week ordinals, so I'll leave that one to you.

Also refer to the [date functions documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

After some self study i used this query

```
select 
a.id_assc,a.name_assc,b.from_date,b.to_date,
(datediff(to_date,from_date)+1) as num_days,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'PL' then (datediff(to_date,from_date)+1)*1 else 0 end) as planned,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'UPL' then (datediff(to_date,from_date)+1)*1 else 0 end) as unplanned,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'SL' then (datediff(to_date,from_date)+1)*1 else 0 end) as sick,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'HDL' then (datediff(to_date,from_date)+1)*1 else 0 end) as halfday,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'AL' then (datediff(to_date,from_date)+1)*1 else 0 end) as annual,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'OL' then (datediff(to_date,from_date)+1)*1 else 0 end) as optional,
 sum(case when leave_typ = 'H' then (datediff(to_date,from_date)+1)*1 else 0 end) as holiday
from associate a
 left join attendance b on a.id_mgr_fk=b.mgr_assc_fk and a.id=b.id_emp_fk
where yearweek(`from_date`) = yearweek(curdate()) and 
 yearweek(`to_date`) = yearweek(curdate()) and b.mgr_assc_fk='1'
 group by b.id_emp_fk, b.from_date, b.to_date;
```

to have the output for the current week which is like 
[image: output]
and things are cool. In the above query the number of days between the dates is calculated including both the weekends. So I searched in stack exchange and found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828948/mysql-function-to-find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates) which is great but when i tried using it with the query

```
select from_date, to_date,
 (5 * (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date) DIV 7) + 
 MID('0123455501234445012333450122234501101234000123450', 7 * 
 WEEKDAY(from_date) + WEEKDAY(to_date) + 1)) as num_days
from attendance;
```

I got the result in exponential form like [image: num_of_days_calc]

Not sure where i am making mistake. 
Any further help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know if that formula is correct but you omitted a detail that's probably important. The `MID` function in that solution has three arguments, not two. The one you missed is a final `1`. So instead of `MID(... + 1)` it should be `MID(... + 1, 1)`. You can take another look at that answer to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my previous answer to calculate the number of days excluding the weekends and holidays, i used @Havrla's answer [WORKDAYS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27850428/9506858)
to calculate the number of days between two given dates and got the output as expected! Thanks to the members!!!
[image: Output]